# How to perform element-wise matrix multiplication on cuda using opencv GpuMat?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

As title says i need to perform element-wise matrix multiplication on cuda using GpuMat. My desired outcome is one that
`cv::Mat mul()` function gives for non-gpu Mats. I can use build-in function as well as i can write kernell for that operation, but i need little help as i am new to cuda.

I allready tried to write kernells to perform that but with no success so far. Also i tried to use mulSpectrums which is available for GpuMats but that function requires matrix to be type CV_32FC2 but i need my matrix to be CV_32F. IF there is literally no way to perform that operation on matrix which is not CV_32FC2, then you can show me efficient way to change matrix type from CV_32F to CV_32FC2 and back to CV_32F.

If anyone has time and will, i would love additional explanation how to perform operations on GpuMat matrices inside CUDA's kernell.

I need that to speed up my SSIM algorithm to lowest possible value as 0.01 sec is way to much for me atm.

But any type of help to perform that mul operation on GpuMat CV_32F inside cuda will be great.

Answer (score 0):

An element wise multiplication can be performed with cv::cuda::multiply.
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d34/group__cudaarithm__elem.html

You can also study the NPP libraries:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/group__image__mul.html